# Is there a way to write whole IEnumerable<T> within one Console.Write(line)?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, console.writeline

I have the following code

```
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = 
        Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
        .Reverse();
    Func<int, string> outputFormat = x => x + "...";
    IEnumerable<string> countdown = numbers.Select(outputFormat);
    foreach (string s in countdown)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Is there a way to "eliminate" foreach loop from the code, something like

```
Console.Write(countdown.EnumerateOverItems())
```

without actually writing custom method (e.g. using LINQ or delegates somehow)?

Comment: Would `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", countdown));` do the trick?

Comment: Optionally `countdown.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, countdown));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, countdown));
```

Note that in older versions of .NET, there is no overload for `string.Join` that take `IEnumerable<T>`, only a `string[]`, and in this case you need something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, countdown.ToArray()));
```

For completeness, if the collection does not contain `string` elements, you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, countdown.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method:

```
public static void WriteLines<T> (this IEnumerable<T> @this)
{
    foreach (T item in @this)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
new[]{ "a", "b" }.WriteLines();
```

Advantages:

1. There will be less string allocations.
2. Less code on usage.

Disadvatages:

1. Custom method, mode code.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but this is definitely an alternative approach if ever memory would be a problem. +1